# Finding nearest values (top and bottom) for given value

Tags: c#, linear-interpolation

I have dataset which contains Value and DateTime and another dataset which represent timeline. Timeline in this case consist rounded times each apart by 15 minutes, but it can be 30 or 60 minutes... I would like calculate linear interpolation for certain times. Those time are in that another dataset.

The question is how to find closest time and value, i.e. times between certain time?

Here is my implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Items> items = Items.GetItems();
        List<DateTime> dt = GenerateTimeLine(items[0].Time, items[items.Count - 1].Time, 15);

        DateTime X1 = items[0].Time;
        double Y1 = items[0].Value;

        DateTime X2 = items[1].Time;
        double Y2 = items[1].Value;


        DateTime X = dt[0];
        double newValue = LinearInterpolation(X.ToOADate(), X1.ToOADate(), X2.ToOADate(), Y1, Y2);
    }
```

Here above I know the start time and end time but I would like to have somekind of query which will take each time for TimeLine dataset and check for each time closese times, take values and interpolate

```
    static double LinearInterpolation(double X, double X1, double X2, double Y1, double Y2)
    {
        if ((X2 - X1) == 0)
        {
            return (Y1 + Y2) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return Y1 + (X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1);
        }

    }

    private static List<DateTime> GenerateTimeLine(DateTime start, DateTime end, int interval)
    {
        List<DateTime> lstD = new List<DateTime>();            

        int res = interval / 2;
        int mod = (interval / 2) % 2;
        int sec = 0;

        if (interval == 1)
            sec = 30;
        else if (interval == 0)
            sec = 0;

        var tempStart = start.AddMinutes(interval).AddSeconds(sec);
        var tempEnd = end.AddMinutes(interval).AddSeconds(sec);
        DateTime st = new DateTime(tempStart.Year, tempStart.Month, tempStart.Day, tempStart.Hour, (tempStart.Minute / interval) * interval, 0);
        DateTime en = new DateTime(tempEnd.Year, tempEnd.Month, tempEnd.Day, tempEnd.Hour, (tempEnd.Minute / interval) * interval, 0);

        lstD.Add(st);

        while (st <= en)
        {
            st = st.AddMinutes(interval);
            lstD.Add(st);
        }

        return lstD;
    }

}

public class Items
{

    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public static List<Items> GetItems()
    {

        string input =
            "| 31         | 2019-03-10 20:39:15 |\n" +
            "| 12         | 2019-03-10 20:44:16 |\n" +
            "| 12         | 2019-03-10 20:51:16 |\n" +
            "| 33         | 2019-03-10 21:08:44 |\n" +
            "| 33         | 2019-03-10 21:09:16 |\n" +
            "| 11         | 2019-03-10 21:24:17 |\n" +
            "| 9          | 2019-03-10 21:36:18 |\n" +
            "| 14         | 2019-03-10 21:50:18 |\n" +
            "| 15         | 2019-03-10 22:09:19 |\n" +
            "| 16         | 2019-03-10 22:24:19 |\n" +
            "| 31         | 2019-03-10 22:39:20 |\n" +
            "| 3          | 2019-03-10 22:54:20 |\n" +
            "| 34         | 2019-03-10 23:09:21 |\n" +
            "| 10         | 2019-03-10 23:24:20 |\n" +
            "| 17         | 2019-03-10 23:39:22 |\n" +
            "| 18         | 2019-03-10 23:54:23";

        List<Items> items = new List<Items>();

        string line = "";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] lineArray = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Items newDate = new Items()
            {                   
                Value = int.Parse(lineArray[0]),
                Time = DateTime.Parse(lineArray[1])
            };

            items.Add(newDate);

        }

        return items;
    }

}
```

Comment: Clearly "find minimum of all values that are bigger than a given one" (which seem to be what you are asking) should not be a problem in itself - `Where(x=> x>10).Min()`... Are you looking for faster than liner time and have trouble with binary search implementation or sorting?

Comment: Honestly I'm new in this field, I'm not sure how to do with LINQ, but now you are mentioning faster than linear time and binary search it seems that there are other ways to implement this... Don't know which is better...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out so here is the code if someone will have similar problem

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{                
  List<Dates> dates = Dates.GetDates();
  List<DateTime> lstTimeLine = GenerateTimeLine(dates[0].Time, dates[dates.Count-1].Time, 10);

  List<Dates> lstInterpolated = new List<Dates>();
  foreach(var itm in lstTimeLine)
  {
       var target = itm;
       Console.WriteLine("############################ X = " + itm);
       var smaller = dates.Last(x => x.Time <= target);
       var bigger = dates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Time >= target);
       if (bigger == null)
           bigger = smaller;

       Console.WriteLine(smaller.ID + " " + smaller.Time + " " + smaller.Value);
       Console.WriteLine(bigger.ID + " " + bigger.Time + " " + bigger.Value); }
}
```

Probably there is a better solution but this fully satisfies what I wanted.